# Can't add new dataframe to global environment after using rm function

Tags: r, rstudio

Basically, I wanted to reload a datframe in R. At first, I just used reload but nothing would change. So, I used the rm() function to delete the dataframe from my global environment but now I can't seem to add it back in anymore. Changing Names didn't work sadly. I already reinstalled R and the problem persists.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is my code:

```
 ## Sniffy will nicht ##

library(jtools)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)

setwd("~/Privat/Studium/R/AP 2 Sniffy/Konditionierung_higherorder")

compound_daten <- read.table(file = 'Ex13_Higherorderconditioning.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)

# 01 Datenmanipulation

data_higherorder <- compound_daten %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  rename(stage = Stage,  
         trial_type = Trial, 
         movrat = `Movement.Ratio`, 
         trial_no = rowid) %>% 
  select(stage, trial_type, trial_no, movrat) %>% 
  mutate(stage = factor(stage, labels = c("Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3")),
         trial_type = as.factor(trial_type) %>% 
           mutate(movrat= as.numeric(movrat))
```

Comment: You cannot load the `compound_daten` into R?

Comment: @Julian That I can load. But I won't receive a new dataframe upon data_higherorder <- compound_daten

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Nope Nothing, which is weird

Comment: Did you try it step by step, e.g. just `compound_daten %>% 
  rowid_to_column()` ? Does nothing happen?

Comment: yeah it does not work from the very first line